# How to invoke PascalScripts UnitImporter from command line

Tags: delphi, scripting, pascal, pascalscript

I want to know if there is a way to start the PSUnitImporter.exe from command line. What I want to do is to have the import file created automatically as a Pre-Build Event.

So far I have found out that when running PSUnitImporter.exe "C:\folder\source.pas" it will invoke the Importer gui and automatically load the file. It will not do the conversion though and it shows the GUI which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gui itself isn't capable of doing that, however the source for the program is in svn at  [pascalscript project page](http://code.remobjects.com/p/pascalscript). A few slight changes there will let you do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CK who pointed me to the pascalscript projet page. I checked out the sourcecode there and found out that it already includes a project for a Commandline importer. 
All I needed to do is compile this project and I was done. I wonder why this "CMDimp.exe" is not included in the Pascralscript setup.